# How add a new _link to an entity using spring data rest?

Tags: spring, rest, api, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I want to add an extra link to a entity such as:

```
"_links": {
  "self": {
    "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/organizaciones"
  },
  "profile": {
    "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/profile/organizaciones"
  },
  "search": {
    "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/organizaciones/search"
  },
  "disable": {
    "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/organizaciones/disable"
  }
}
```

The idea behind this scenario is that I need to expose a soft delete via its own link within Organizacion entity... right now I'm only able to do:

`http://localhost:8080/api/organizaciones/search/disable?id=100`

in order to perform the soft delete. How can I achieve this the right way? Or is it my only alternative creating a controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a class extending the ResourceProcessor interface and add it to the spring-context(http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_the_resourceprocessor_interface)
For example

```
@Bean
public ResourceProcessor<Resource<Person>> personProcessor() {

   return new ResourceProcessor<Resource<Person>>() {

     @Override
     public Resource<Person> process(Resource<Person> resource) {

      resource.add(new Link("http://localhost:8080/people", "added-link"));
      return resource;
     }
   };
}
```

Where the Person entity can be replaced with your Organizacion entity.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out, I did what was mentioned by Alex in a comment.

I have to give credit to the father of spring-data-rest to @olivergieke I checked one of his examples, more precise: **restbucks**

First created the following component

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OrganizacionResourceProcessor implements     ResourceProcessor<Resource<Organizacion>>{

private static final String DISABLE_REL = "deshabilitar";
private static final String ENABLE_REL = "habilitar";

private final @NonNull EntityLinks entityLinks;


@Override
public Resource<Organizacion> process(Resource<Organizacion> resource) {
    
    Organizacion organizacion = resource.getContent();
    
    if(organizacion.isEnabled()){
        resource.add(entityLinks.linkForSingleResource(Organizacion.class, organizacion.getId()).slash(DISABLE_REL).withRel(DISABLE_REL));
    }
    if(organizacion.isDisabled()){
        resource.add(entityLinks.linkForSingleResource(Organizacion.class, organizacion.getId()).slash(ENABLE_REL).withRel(ENABLE_REL));
    }
    
    return resource;
}

}
```

Then created the controller to support those two operations...

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/organizaciones")
@ExposesResourceFor(Organizacion.class)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@Transactional
public class OrganizacionController {

private final @NonNull OrganizacionRepository organizacionRepository;
private final @NonNull EntityLinks entityLinks;



@GetMapping(value="/{id}/habilitar")
public ResponseEntity<?> desactivarOrganizacion(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(id);
    
    Organizacion organizacion = organizacionRepository.findOne(id);
    
    if(organizacion == null){
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    
    organizacion.setEstado(Estado.DESHABILITADO);       
    Organizacion pOrg = this.organizacionRepository.save(organizacion);
    
    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.setLocation(this.entityLinks.linkForSingleResource(Organizacion.class, pOrg.getId()).toUri());//construimos el URL       
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(header,HttpStatus.CREATED);
}


@GetMapping(value="/{id}/deshabilitar")
public ResponseEntity<?> activarOrganizacion(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(id);
    
    Organizacion organizacion = organizacionRepository.findOne(id);
    
    if(organizacion == null){
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    
    organizacion.setEstado(Estado.ACTIVO);      
    Organizacion pOrg = this.organizacionRepository.save(organizacion);
    
    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.setLocation(this.entityLinks.linkForSingleResource(Organizacion.class, pOrg.getId()).toUri());//construimos el URL       
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(header,HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

}
```

and that was it.

---

<sub>This was originally added to [Revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40951245/3) of the question.</sub>